# Как узнать какая кнопка нажата?(java)

Tags: java, swing

Есть форма, на этой форме есть кнопки. Их может быть и 100 и 200 и т.д. Как узнать какая кнопка была нажата?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы создаёте программу с множеством кнопок, наверняка каждая кнопка для чего-то предназначена, и при `нажатии` на неё должно происходить `действие`. Тогда для каждой кнопки нужно создать `слушателя`:

```
myButton.addActionListener(e -> {
// что будет, если нажать на кнопку
});
```

Или, можно добавить `слушателей` только для тех кнопок, для которых вы хотите. Если нажать на кнопку, у которой нет слушателя, не произойдет ничего.

Если у всех ваших кнопок и так есть `слушатели` и при нажатии на них уже выполняются какие-то действия, но при нажатии на какие-то определенные кнопки из множества вам нужны особенные действия, то их тоже можно добавить к слушателям этих кнопок. Например, закрытие программы.

Если вы добавляете кнопки через массив, например, так:

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   myPanel.add(new JButton("Button " + i));
}
```

Тогда возникает вопрос, зачем вы поступаете именно так? Можете через цикл добавить кнопки, при нажатии на которые не произойдет ничего (тогда зачем они?), а остальные создать отдельно и добавить для них `слушателей`.

Comment: ![sampel](http://rgho.st/6PQjqVTCl/image.png) хочу реализовать подобное. Кнопки использую потому-что там больше возможностей в стилизации. P.S. В java новичек

Comment: дело в том данные будут выводится из базы, то есть их будут удалять и добавлять и плюс кнопок много, писать для каждой слушателя глупо